# ReferenceError: Headers is not defined error

Tags: reactjs

I'm tring to use a coin API website for a project, I keep encountering the same error:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
            ^

ReferenceError: Headers is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\magshimim\say-hi-to-sheli-from-me\rafaels-crypto-ninja\thingy\server\index.js:14:17)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

that's the code in use:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("apikey", "the API key is here");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: myHeaders
};

const data = fetch("https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/timeseries?start_date=2021-01-01&end_date=2021-12-31", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  //.then(result => console.log(result))
  .then(result => result)
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

console.log(requestOptions);
```

Comment: sorry, updated it

Comment: your code is working fine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this as you should fetch the [hearers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) first.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var myHeaders = new fetch.Headers();
```

Comment: This is a  package `node-fetch` not the `Headers` native from fetch API, nowhere in the documentation linked exists this package or this piece of code

Comment: Yes, `node-fetch` used to go from native `HTTP` to fetch API directly. where is the problem?